# Overriding method with checked exceptions

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have two classes, A and B, where B extends A. I'm having a problem where B introduces an additional feature that comes with an exception `ExceptionC` that doesn't apply in any way shape or form to A, but it won't compile unless A specifies that it `throws ExceptionC`. I understand that this is by design (because of the Liskov Substitution Principle). My question is twofold:

1. What is the reasoning behind the Liskov Substitution Principle? If B extends A, shouldn't it be able to add more features and therefore exceptions?
2. What would be a better way to do this? It feels wrong to add a non-applicable exception to the superclass.

Specific situation:

I am writing an implementation of Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe in Java. Basically take a tic-tac-toe grid and fill it with tic-tac-toe grids, like this:

```
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
#################
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
#################
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | |
```

You start in the center, and wherever X goes in that grid, O goes in the grid corresponding to that on the larger one, so after two moves it might look like this:

```
 | |O# | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
#################
 | | #X| | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
#################
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | | 
 | | # | | # | |
```

And if the target grid is full or has already been won, the next person can choose which grid to go in.

I have two normal classes, two exception classes, and an interface.

- TTTBoard implements Board
- UltimateTTTBoard extends TTTBoard implements Board
- TTTBoard.move throws LocationTakenException
- UltimateTTTBoard.move throws LocationTakenException,TargetBoardFullException

Note that in standard tic-tac-toe, there is only one board so TargetBoardFullException is completely non-applicable.

Am I doing this wrong? Should I not be using exceptions for this?

Comment: The reasoning behind LSB is the word *substitution*, so if B does some stuff quite differently and needs more code in order to work with it (like a `try/catch` block), then you can't replace/substitute that with `C` without further refactorings. So `B` can do stuff differently, but shouldn't break rules defined by `A`.

Comment: B should catch ExceptionC and transform it into some kind of exception that A is allowed to throw, perhaps by wrapping it.  Or better still B's exceptions could be subclasses of A's exceptions.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps it would be easier to understand if I gave the exact situation. I will update the question now.

Comment: And what does "move" do? Is it a players move? If yes, than should that really handle the switch to another board? Does that still agree with the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)?

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows why Java doesn't allow changing the contract:

```
class A {
    public void method() {
        // do something
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void method() throws IOException {  // <- compile error here
        // do something and throw and exception
    }
}

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.method();  // to try or not to try, that's the question now.
    }
}
```

Of course, it doesn't compile. But if it would, would we have to catch an IOException in the main method (because it's a `B` instance) or not (because we call the method on the interface)?

Comment: *"on the interface"* `A` is not an interface though.

Comment: I understand what the code is doing. I'm just having trouble grasping why you would want to do A a = new B().

Comment: And in addition, what should I do instead? I've updated the question with specific circumstances.

Comment: @DuncanX.Simpson *"why you would want to do A a = new B()"* -> ["Program to an interface". What does it mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1992384)

Comment: Yes but A is not an interface. B builds on A but does something different.

Comment: @DuncanX.Simpson The important thing isn't if `A` is an interface or not, the important thing is that `A` is the parent type and you don't bother anymore if the actual object is `B`, `C` or `D`, since the are all childs of `A`. This is what LSP is all about.

Comment: Okay, I see. So since B does something significantly different from A, should B not extend A? They use many identical methods, which is why I chose to extend in the first place.

Comment: You can extend the behaviour as long as it throws an exception which is a subclass of the parent (or the same exception). It is required because otherwise the whole application could break if a naive coder throws an exception which can't be handled (assuming the application was built around the parent and all the specific exceptions were handled correctly).